# SQLAlchemy - Copy records, update one column, and save as new records

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Using SQLAlchemy, I am simply trying to query a set of records such as follows

```py
session.query(MyTable).filter_by(foreign_id=413).all()
```

Then, I just need to make a copy of these records, change the `foreign_id`, and save them back to the same table as new records. I can't think of an efficient way to do this right now. The only thing that I have come up with is looping through the result set, creating new records that share all the same properties besides `foreign_id` and then bulk saving these new records.

It is important that I keep the original records in tact, so simply updating the rows is not an option.

If it helps, here is essentially the MyTable object

```py
class MyTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'my_table'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    col_a = Column(String(64))
    col_b = Column(String(64))
    foreign_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('other_table.id'))
```

In this example, I would want to keep `col_a` and `col_b` the same, but update the `foreign_id` and `id` columns.

Answer (score 1):

If you were using Django ORM, you could simply set the id field to None and save it, creating a copied record, assuming the primary id field was auto-generated.

With SQLAlchemy, this will not work, nor does it make sense in pure SQL terms.
An efficient and extensible way to achieve this is:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import class_mapper

recs = session.query(MyTable).filter_by(foreign_id=413).all()
for rec in recs:
    newrec = MyTable()
    for item in [p.key for p in class_mapper(MyTable).iterate_properties]:
        if item not in ['id', 'foreign_id']:
            setattr(newrec, item, getattr(rec, item))
    # assign foreign field as appropriate...
    session.add(newrec)
    session.commit()
```